# SQL subquery count

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have a table LOCATION with columns like ID,Applicant ID, Applicants(Work applicants /School applicants) and country. I now have to query How many work applicants applied to a school applications in a different country than their own. 
I tried something like this but did not work:

```
SELECT Count(applicants) 
FROM   location 
WHERE  applicants = 'Work' 
       AND country NOT IN (SELECT country 
                           FROM   locations 
                           WHERE  applicants = 'School')
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Postgresql?

Comment: Tip of today: `NOT IN (sub-query)` is tricky when it comes to _null_ values. Use `NOT EXISTS` instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: using postgresql

Comment: What mean doesnt work? wrong result? Error? Do you have an aplicant_id? otherwise how you know if apply on multiple countries

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yes ID column is applicant ID and I am getting no values (blank). So there are about 30 work applicants and 20 school applicants

Comment: so do you have location_id too?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I am so sorry for the mistake in question, yes I do have location ID also.

Comment: The database design makes it harder to understand the task. A location table should contain locations identified by a unique location ID along with some city name and street or the like. Your table is either an applicant table with a unique applicant ID or a bridge table holding applicant/location relations. What is the table's unique key?

Comment: Which column tells us where an applicant is from and which column tells us in which country they applied? Please show sample data and explain what a record in the table represents. From the applicant ID I gather that there is an applicant table holding the home country maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Count(applicants) 
FROM   location l
WHERE  applicants = 'Work' 
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                       FROM location o
                       WHERE l.applicant_id = o.applicant_id
                         AND l.country <> o.country
                         AND o.applicants = 'School')
```

This look for all applicants with `'Work'` but doesn't have applicants with `'School'` in a different country. But they can have `'School'` on the same country